# Remove Stop Words in Python List Using List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, nlp, nltk, stop-words

Python noob so sorry for simple question but I can't find the exact solution for my situation.

I've got a python list, I want to remove stop words from a list. My code isn't removing the stopword if it's paired with another token.

```
    from nltk.corpus import stopwords
    rawData = ['for', 'the', 'game', 'the movie']
    text = [each_string.lower() for each_string in rawData]
    newText = [word for word in text if word not in stopwords.words('english')]
    print(newText)
```

current output:
['game', 'the movie']

desired output
['game', 'movie']

I'd prefer to use list comprehension for this.

Comment: correct. it doesn't yield 'movie'. it currently yields 'the movie'.

hence my comment that 'movie' is the desired output.

Comment: If you're testing for stop words such as 'the' in a phrase such as 'the movie' then you should split the phrase into ['the', 'movie'] and test each of the words in the phrase. Testing the phrase itself against an individual stop word won't work.

Comment: thanks. how do i do that?

Comment: You can get a list of individual words using `[word for phrase in text for word in phrase.split()]` which will yield `['for', 'the', 'game', 'the', 'movie']` and then use your 2nd list comprehension to remove stop words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to do this because list comprehensions are not my thing. Anyways, this is how I did it:

```py
import functools

stopwords = ["for", "the"]

rawData = ['for', 'the', 'game', 'the movie']
lst = functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [i.split() for i in rawData])
newText = [word for word in lst if word not in stopwords]
print(newText)
```

Basically, line 4 splits the list values to make a nested list AND turns the nested list one dimensional.